# Codeigniter showing blank page with php5.6 and 7.2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4

seniors,
I want to website migration from CentOS-8  to ubuntu 18.04. on Ubuntu have the same setup with LAMP setup with PHP 7.2 but Codeigniter getting the blank page.

**note: i have also try it on 5.6 but getting same issue.**

**Codeigniter version**
`'CI_VERSION',      '1.7.2'`

I have set in application/config/constant.php

```
define('DEVELOPMENT', FALSE);
error_reporting(1);
```

my appliaction/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('jempe_form', 'jempe_db', 'database', 'form_validation', 'employees_library', 'session', 'template_library');
```

after i was getting the mysql error in screen and logsthen i was set in application/config/database.php
`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";`
to
`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";`
fixed the issue after change in databases.php but still Codeigniter showing blank page and have no error in error.logs
i have also enable the error reporting in php.ini
and

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
extension=php_mysqli
```

also i have try with `extension=mysqli` and `extension=mysqli.so` and php -m | grep mysql

```
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

I have above mention setting but did getting any error logs.
please help how it could be solved the blank screen issue.
thanks

Comment: do you try new version of CI?

Comment: No, I have CI 1.7. i want to move to another server.

Comment: may be you have short tags in your code please check for <? ?> such tags or allow short open tag "short_open_tag ini setting" .

Comment: how i can allow the short tag in CI?

Comment: edited my previous comment, it's php ini setting short_open_tag=On

Comment: added in php.ini but still the same issue.